# Ocultar diferentes opções (actions) para diferentes perfis de usuários

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, visual-studio-2013

Estou em um projeto em que tenho 3 diferentes níveis de perfis: **Administrador**, **Professor** e **Coordenador**. Eu já tenho o módulo de login, cadastros e tal.

O que acontece é que eu queria que para cada tipo de perfil aparecesse somente o que lhe é permitido, ocultando as partes do sistema que ele não pode acessar de acordo com sua hierarquia.

Isso é direto na *view*? Se for, como se faz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outra situação possível seria, para se ter os perfis diferentes, criar partials correspondente  a cada perfil de usuário que existe no sistema. Ou seja, se você tiver 3 perfis diferentes, separe o sistema em áreas e decore as actions com as permissões possíveis, de acordo com o seu sistema e a ai cada perfil acessa somente a sua área.
Resumindo, crie uma action que retorne uma partial específica pra aquele tipo de perfil. Isso soluciona todo o problema com permissões, pois cada perfil somente pode acessar o que lhe é permitido, o que não é, não acessa !
Para criar essas permissões pode-se usar como base [esse link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16691/login-com-diferentes-perfis) como base para fazer essa operação, que é inclusive, outra pergunta minha.
Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: O problema disso é que uma inclusão de perfil acarreta em você ter que modificar o sistema novamente. Considerando um cenário em que praticamente o sistema não muda, tudo bem ser assim. O problema é quando as permissões mudam com alguma frequência não desprezível.

Comment: É o problema dessa abordagem é o retrabalho caso alguma lógica no perfil mude. Porque talvez tenha que mudar a partial e tal e mudar na decoração do controller. Mas cada abordagem tem seus prós e contras né,  mas pode servir pra alguém que esteja precisando de alguma luz pra fazer isso.

Answer (score 6):

Considerando que seu projeto usa no mínimo `Membership` ou `ASP.NET Identity`, anote em cima de cada View o seguinte atributo:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador, Professor, Coordenador")]
public ActionResult MinhaAction() { ... }
```

Para autorizar algum usuário na `Role`, use o seguinte comando em alguma parte do seu código:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole("LoginDoUsuario", "Administrador");
```

Para verificar no seu código se o usuário pertence a alguma `Role`, use:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrador")) { ... }
```

Para retirar o usuário de uma `Role`, use:

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("LoginDoUsuario", "Administrador");
```

Para Views, o princípio é o mesmo:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrador")) { ... }
```

Para verificar as `Roles` do usuário atual:

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

Ou de um usuário específico:

```
@Roles.GetRolesForUser("LoginDoUsuario")
```

Aliás, você pode usar o atributo sem especificar `Role` apenas para verificar se o usuário está logado:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MinhaAction() { ... }
```

Se nenhum esquema de autenticação for especificado, sua aplicação usará o `SimpleMembership` se for MVC4 ou então `ASP.NET Identity` com *Basic Authentication* se for MVC5.

Como dito, é possível personalizar o esquema de autenticação reimplementando algumas classes. Em todo caso, esta parte já serviria para outra pergunta.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta.Mas estou usando o Forms Autentication ! E dessa forma, caso um professor tente acessar uma área que ele não possa, o sistema rejeita a identidade dele e faz o logout. Mas o que eu queria na verdade é, por exemplo, um Professor, não pode adicionar ou excluir ou mesmo editar os dados do aluno, só pode visualizar e detalhar os dados. Então nessa caso, como que faço pra ocultar os links de editar, adicionar e remover na view Index ?

Comment: Usando esta linha da resposta: `if (User.IsInRole("Administrador")) { ... }`.

Comment: Diretamente na View ?

Comment: Sim, pode ser na View, inclusive, com o `@` na frente.

Comment: Ahh entendi. E no if eu deixaria em branco assim mesmo ? Ou tem alguma verificação a fazer ai ? Poderia colocar mais de um perfil nessa linha ai ?

Comment: É outra função. Vou colocar na resposta.

Comment: Cigano, não funcionou, eu coloquei o if, e a opção não aparece pra nenhum perfil...

Comment: Acho que é novamente o caso de abrir outra pergunta, desta vez detalhando o que foi feito na solução. Aí consigo sugerir o que fazer.