# Tela de login com membership e mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como eu faço uma tela de login usando o membership e mvc 5? Aliás, como eu uso o membership?

Comment: Não sei se é isso que você deseja, mas dê uma olhada nesse tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16995/ocultar-diferentes-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-actions-para-diferentes-perfis-de-usu%C3%A1rios

Comment: Mais ou menos isso. Ainda não testei, mas acho ser isso sim.

Comment: Ache esse outro tópico aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22004/permiss%C3%B5es-de-usu%C3%A1rios

Answer (score 2):

## Como eu faço uma tela de login usando o membership e mvc 5?

Vou ensinar o jeito pelo método **Simple Membership**. Aprendido este, posso passar como faz um esquema de autenticação mais sofisticado.

Primeiro você precisa inicializar o Membership. Isto normalmente é feito por um `Filter`, como este logo abaixo:

### SeuProjeto/Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using SeuProjeto.Models;

namespace SeuProjeto.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isto cria o mínimo do mínimo para o seu sistema de logins, no caso, 4 tabelas internas e mais uma tabela chamada `UserProfiles`, que vai ser usada para registrar os logins e senhas da sua aplicação.

Note também que há um tal de `UsersContext`, que deve ser criado como um `Model` no diretório `Models`. Aqui coloco também mais alguns modelos adicionais que serão usados para configurar suas Views:

### SeuProjeto\Models\AccountModels.cs

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
}

public class LocalPasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RememberMe", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalLogin
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Feito isso, você precisará de um `Controller` para coordenar as ações de login. Colocarei um exemplo meu, alterado de um exemplo da Microsoft.

Note que o `Filter` que implementamos acima é inicializado aqui (`InitializeSimpleMembership`).

### SeuProjeto/Controllers/AccountController.cs

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    // [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
        {
            string ownerAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserName(provider, providerUserId);
            ManageMessageId? message = null;

            // Only disassociate the account if the currently logged in user is the owner
            if (ownerAccount == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                // Use a transaction to prevent the user from deleting their last login credential
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
                {
                    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                    if (hasLocalAccount || OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name).Count > 1)
                    {
                        OAuthWebSecurity.DeleteAccount(provider, providerUserId);
                        scope.Complete();
                        message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage

        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
        {
            bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasLocalAccount)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                    bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                    try
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                    }

                    if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
                // OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Unable to create local account. An account with the name \"{0}\" may already exist.", User.Identity.Name));
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string provider = null;
            string providerUserId = null;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Insert a new user into the database
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
                    // Check if user already exists
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Insert name into the profile table
                        db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = model.UserName });
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
                        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveExternalLogins()
        {
            ICollection<OAuthAccount> accounts = OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            List<ExternalLogin> externalLogins = new List<ExternalLogin>();
            foreach (OAuthAccount account in accounts)
            {
                AuthenticationClientData clientData = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(account.Provider);

                externalLogins.Add(new ExternalLogin
                {
                    Provider = account.Provider,
                    ProviderDisplayName = clientData.DisplayName,
                    ProviderUserId = account.ProviderUserId,
                });
            }

            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = externalLogins.Count > 1 || OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            return PartialView("_RemoveExternalLoginsPartial", externalLogins);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
        }

        internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
        {
            public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
            {
                Provider = provider;
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            }

            public string Provider { get; private set; }
            public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
            }
        }

        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Agora é só implementar as `Views`. As minhas têm Bootstrap:

### Views/Account/Login.cshtml

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.LoginModel
@using SeuProjeto.Resources

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Language.Login;
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

<section id="loginForm">
<h2>@Language.Login</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
    FormMethod.Post, new { @style = "max-width: 330px; padding: 15px; margin: 0 auto;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Language.LoginForm</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Language.UserName })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Language.Password })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="@Language.Login" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") @Language.IfYouDontHaveAnAccount.
    </p>
}
</section>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

### Views/Account/Register.cshtml

```
@using SeuProjeto.Resources

@model SeuProjeto.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Language.Register;
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@Language.CreateANewAccount.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @style = "max-width: 330px; padding: 15px; margin: 0 auto;" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Language.RegistrationForm</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Language.UserName })
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Language.Password })
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = Language.ConfirmPassword })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">@Language.Register</button> 
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

## Aliás, como eu uso o membership?

Tem várias maneiras. Essa é a mais simples (eu sei... não é simples), mas implementando este código acho que os aspectos devem ficar mais claros.