# Permissões de usuários

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Não sei como posso estar implementando no meu sistemas as permissões de usuários e gostaria que me desse algum norte.

A partir da minha classe:

```
public class Loja_Usuarios
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public bool Pedido { get; set; }
    public bool Produto { get; set; }
    public bool Cliente { get; set; }
    public bool Carrossel { get; set; }
    public bool Carta { get; set; }
    public bool Usuario { get; set; }
    public bool Codigo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public bool Menu { get; set; }
}

public class Loja_Carrossel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome deve ser preenchido")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Imagem deve ser preenchido")]
    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "URL deve ser preenchido")]
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Onde Pedido, Produto, Cliente..., são todas as permissões do usuário.
Porém a partir daqui não sei como fazer isso. Não sei se usa ASP.Net Identity ou outro. Quando fazia isso em outros sistemas, eu só validava se estava logado ou não.

Comment: Procure por temas ligados à "Role/Membership Provider". Uma classe de referência é [RoleProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx).

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge tenho uma pergunta parecida com a sua, então vou colocar o [link aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16691/login-com-diferentes-perfis) pra você ver como que foi feito. Só salientando que em meu sistema, no model de usuários, tenho o atributo Perfil, e faço um Dictionary com os possíveis perfis que existem em meu sistema, e ele procura por esse atributo e restringe as áreas que não podem ser acessadas por determinados perfis. Espero ter ajudado !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou supondo o seguinte nos seus *Models*:

## Models/Loja.cs

```
public class Loja 
{
    [Key]
    public int LojaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Loja_Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

## Models/Loja_Usuario.cs

```
public class Loja_Usuarios
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LojaId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public bool Pedido { get; set; }
    public bool Produto { get; set; }
    public bool Cliente { get; set; }
    public bool Carrossel { get; set; }
    public bool Carta { get; set; }
    public bool Usuario { get; set; }
    public bool Codigo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public bool Menu { get; set; }

    public virtual Loja Loja { get; set; }
}
```

Declare também o seguinte `Enum`:

## Enums/Permissao.cs

```
public enum Permissao 
{
    Pedido,
    Produto,
    Cliente,
    Carrossel,
    Carta,
    Usuario,
    Codigo,
    Ativo,
    Menu
}
```

Implemente seu próprio atributo de autorização:

## Attributes/CustomAuthorizationAttibute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private Permissao[] _permissoes;
    private MeuProjetoContext context = new MeuProjetoContext();

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params Permissao[] permissoes) 
    {
        _permissoes = permissoes;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!_permissoes.Any()) return true;

        var usuarioId = LoggedUserHelper.UsuarioId(httpContext.User);
        var usuario = context.Loja_Usuarios.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == usuarioId);

        foreach (permissao in _permissoes) 
        {
            switch (permissao) 
            {
                case Permissao.Pedido:
                    return usuario.Pedido;
                case Permissao.Produto:
                    return usuario.Produto;
                case Permissao.Cliente:
                    return usuario.Cliente;
                case Permissao.Carrossel:
                    return usuario.Carrossel;
                case Permissao.Carta:
                    return usuario.Carta;
                case Permissao.Usuario:
                    return usuario.Usuario;
                case Permissao.Codigo:
                    return usuario.Codigo;
                case Permissao.Ativo:
                    return usuario.Ativo;
                case Permissao.Menu:
                    return usuario.Menu;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Implemente abaixo pra onde a requisição vai se o usuário não estiver autorizado
    /* protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Error",
                    action = "Unauthorised"
                })
            );
    } */
}
```

Uso no seu `Controller`:

```
// Para poder ter acesso a esta action, o usuário precisa ter permissão ou de 
// Cliente, ou de Usuario.
[CustomAuthorize(Permissao.Cliente, Permissao.Usuario)]
public ActionResult Index() 
{
   ...
}
```

É possível usar apenas para verificar se o usuário está autenticado.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index() 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: está dando erro aqui:  foreach (permissao in permissoes)

Comment: Fiz uma edição para você visualizar melhor minhas classes models.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Qual erro?

Comment: The type or namespace name "permissao" could not be found...

Comment: Corrigi esta linha pra: `foreach (permissao in _permissoes) `. Veja agora.

Comment: Deu certo aqui... Agora esta com erro nos cases! "case permissao.Pedido:" erro: "Members 'Ui.Web.Enums.Permissao.Pedido' cannot be accessed with as instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: para resolver o erro do foreach fiz o seguinte: foreach (Enums.Permissao permissao in _permissoes)

Comment: Por que está `permissao.Pedido` em minúsculo? Tem que ser maiúsculo: `Permissao.Pedido`, porque se refere ao `enum`, e não à variável do `foreach`.

Comment: Consegui aqui @Cigano, quando o usuário logar ficaria assim: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(id, false);