# Como redirecionar para outra página quando usuário não tem autorização

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Tenho meu `Custom AuthorizeAttribute`.

Ele funciona perfeitamente do jeito que quero, porém ele sempre direciona o usuário para `/Account/Login`, gostaria que redirecionasse para outra página que eu escolhesse, já que ele não tem autorização, como faço isso?

Lembrando é Autorização e não autenticação.

Na autenticação a página está correta, fazer o *login*.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo/1911#1911 Por favor, colabore na formatação, você está sendo bastante beneficiado no site e poderia ajudar a manter as postagens organizadas. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas/1297#1297

Comment: ok @bigown, coloquei no título pois esqueci das tags, desculpe

Answer (score 1):

Com base nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22004/permiss%C3%B5es-de-usu%C3%A1rios).

Adicione o seguinte método no `CustomAuthorizationAttibute`:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            // A sessão está nula ou vazia, não existe usuário logado.
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Login"
                })
            );
        }
        else
        {
            // Usuário não tem permissão.
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "NaoAutorizado"

                })
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecione normalmente utilizando o Metodo redirect do MVC.

E coloque no web.config uma tag location atribuindo a autoriação anonima somente para a sua action (url)

```
<location path="login/SessaoExpirada">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```