# Permissões no Login

Tags: c#

Estou a fazer uma aplicação em C# onde eu criei uma base de dados para o sistema de login onde tenho os utilizadores criados. Nesse sistema de login eu queria adicionar permissões a determinados utilizadores. Por exemplo, o programa detectar que é o admin a fazer login e habilita um determinado botão, enquanto se for outro utilizador esse botão fica desabilitado.

Isso é possível fazer? E como?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Permissões de usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22004/permiss%c3%b5es-de-usu%c3%a1rios)

Comment: É um webforms ou um MVC?

Comment: é um projeto em windows forms

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um campo na tabela para saber o tipo de usuário e/ou hierárquia para saber 'como irá' validar quem terá direitos aos componentes de cada módulo.

O exemplo abaixo é apenas uma base, pois não sei como está montada sua tabela. Mas inicialmente é desta forma que você pode começar a pensar sobre sua dúvida.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Usuario objUsuario = new Usuario();
                if (objUsuario.ConsultarUsuario(txtLogin.Text, txtSenha.Text) > 0)
                {
                    if (objUsuario.ChecarAcessoUsuario("opcCaixa", "", Metodos.codUsuario, Metodos.codGrupo))
                    {                        
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Usuário não possui acesso ao caixa loja!", "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login ou senha inválidos!","Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }







public bool ChecarAcessoUsuario(string menu, string acao, int usuario, string grupo)
        {
            try
            {
                var segnivel = ConsultarSegnivel1(menu);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(segnivel) && ConsultarDireitos(segnivel, usuario, grupo))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                segnivel = ConsultarSegnivel2(menu);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(segnivel) && ConsultarDireitos(segnivel, usuario, grupo))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```