# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Alguém pode me ajudar com o erro abaixo? Implementei me baseando nesse link [PermissionCookie](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16691/login-com-diferentes-perfis)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu `Session[".PermissionCookie"]` tem valor nullo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro acontece por um motivo muito simples: depois de um determinado tempo, pré definido em seu `web.config`, o *cookie* é deletado do navegador.

Isso é uma certa precaução pra sua aplicação.

Mas para driblar esse erro é simples:

Vá no seu `web.config` em seu projeto é só acrescentar a *tag* `<autentication>`, como segue abaixo.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms timeout="28" loginUrl="/Autenticacao/Index"></forms>
</authentication>   
</system.web>
```

Explicando: O *timeout* é o tempo que o *cookie* vai ficar ativo no navegador e depois que o tempo expirar redireciona para a página de login.

Como usou minha pergunta como base, não fiz nenhum tratamento para que mostrasse alguma mensagem para o usuário, mas caso queira implementar essa ideia, seria legal. É uma alternativa para não mostrar essa telinha do IIS.

## EDIT

Esse erro também ocorre porque necessariamente algum usuário precisa estar logado na página onde o *.PermisionCookie* é utilizado.

Isso acontece porque as informações do usuário são verificadas nesse *cookie* que é criado assim que a *Session* sobe no sistema, ou seja, assim que o usuário realmente loga no sistema. Se não tiver nenhum usuário logado, a *Session* não é criada e, por consequência, nem o *cookie* e por isso esse erro aparece, por não saber que *cookie* é esse que a página ta requerendo, e seta o valor do *cookie* como *null*.